# Set command line parameter in build.gradle

Tags: gradle, build

One of the gradle tasks I'm running is doing too many printouts and since I can't adjust its inner log level I'm trying to run it with the `-q` command line option to restrict the printout to error level only. That works fine but I also need to run the task when I don't have access to the command line (like from inside IntelliJ and when running other tasks that are depending on it.)
Is there a way that I can specify in `build.gradle` that this task should always be run with `-q`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that it's not possible to do it now for a single task - there is an [open issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1010) for supporting such a case, which is still open.

Answer (score 1):

You can set [a global log level](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties) in `gradle.properties`

> `org.gradle.logging.level=(quiet,warn,lifecycle,info,debug)`
>
> When set to quiet, warn, lifecycle, info, or debug, Gradle will use this log level. The values are not case sensitive. The lifecycle
>   level is the default. See Choosing a log level.

It's not possible to reduce the scope to the task level but at least for test purpose, it will work.